# How can I run a php script when a user clicks a link without redirecting to that particular php page, and download an mp3 file at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I have an mp3 file whose downloads value am counting and updating well in a MySQL database when I run my php script by going to the scripts address in the address bar like this https://groupkse.net/music_files/countDownloads.php?id=3. My issue is I want to run this php script without redirecting my browser to this location, when a link is clicked to download that mp3. NB: The mp3 is in the same directory with the countDownloads.php and the page containing the link is in a different directory, but on the same server, i.e. https://groupkse.net/songReleaseHtml/megaMuQuarantine.php

Code from countDownloads.php is below:

```
<?php

//Make connection with database

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "groupkse_music_admin", "my_Password", "groupkse_music_downloads");

//Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exiit();
}

//Passing which song needs download increment

$incomingData = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$data = substr($incomingData, strpos($incomingData, 'id=') + 3);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data);
//echo "$id";

$query = "UPDATE `music_downloads` SET `downloads_number` = `downloads_number` + 1 WHERE `Id` = '$id'";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);

?>
```

And code from my link in the megaMuQuarantine.php:

```
<a href="../music_files/mu_quarantine.mp3" download="file.mp3" title="Download song" class="downloadButton" id="dButton">Download MP3</a>
```

Comment: Use Javascript and preventDefault()

Comment: Hello nikistag, I am only a short while into my programming career and am just kind of entering my intermediate level! So, kindly assist me with a short code snippet for that JavaScript preventDefault() method.

Comment: Hey nikistag, also bear in mind that there are two things involved; 1. The file has to download, which is where the anchor tag is pointing, and 2. I want the php script to fire when that link is clicked.

Comment: If you are happy with Opening the Download link in another tab then adding `target="_blank"` will be enough. If you want the process to be complete in the background then you need AJAX functionality.

Comment: Download doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @nikistag I have just updated the page. I left a small extension which shouldn't  have been there in my anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="../music_files/mu_quarantine.mp3" download="file.mp3" title="Download song" class="downloadButton" id="dButton">Download MP3</a>
```

Add this input to point to the php file that counts downloads.

```
<input type="hidden" id="downloadCounter" value="LINK TO COUNTER" />
```

Put this at the bottom of your web page:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("dButton").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            location.relod;
        }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", document.getElementById("downloadCounter").value(), true);
        xhttp.send(); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks nikistag, but also see that there are two things involved; 1. I need the file to download, which is where the anchor tag is pointing, and 2. I want the php script to fire when that link is clicked. What can I add to the JavaScript so that it fires that php script in the different directory?

Comment: @KlemLloydMwenya Use Ajax

Answer (score 1):

To execute a PHP code without actual page action requires AJAX as pointed out by @nikistag; security issues being secondary as per now. For file downloads, this can be tricky and I would advice that you go with the 'download' attribute for html5. If such links with download attribute is clicked, it will download the file - major file types already covered. Now figure out a way to create this dynamic link; you can easily do this with jQuery or pure JS and perform auto-click on it when your button is clicked.

```
//hide this somewhere in your current page 
 <a id="choiceMusic" href="../music_files/default_music.mp3" download> 

//to change href according to choice, use something like this in that master function 
var  currentMusic = "../music_files/"+ chosenOne.mp3;
$("#choiceMusic").attr("href", currentMusic);

//when ready to call this; //if fails, try: $('#choiceMusic')[0].click(function(){}); 
$('#choiceMusic').trigger('click');
```

Ensure that all these happen after the document if fully ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     //safe to do your staff now,
});
```

Now call your master function and don't forget to include your Ajax function for updates

Answer (score 0):

I put together the information from the above answers and came up with a solution that works for me. I hope it's a practice that is allowed!

1. Made two interdependent links with one of them invisible:

```
<a href="#dButton" class="downloadButton" id="dButton" onClick="downloadMP3()" title="Download song">Download MP3</a>

<a href="../music_files/mu_quarantine.mp3" download id="downloadSong" hidden></a>
```

Some AJAX and another JavaScript function to run my PHP file in the background and auto click the invisible link:

```
            var dButton = document.getElementById("dButton"),
                hidden_dLink = document.getElementById("downloadSong");

                // Act on clicks to a elements

                function downloadMP3() {
                    // Clicks the hidden anchor tag
                    hidden_dLink.click();   
                }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#dButton').on('click', function () {   

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://groupkse.net/music_files/countDownloads.php?id=3',
                        method: 'GET',
                        xhrFields: {
                            responseType: 'blob'
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                            a.href = url;
                            a.download = 'file.mp3';
                            document.body.append(a);
                            a.click();
                            a.remove();
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                        }                   
                    });
                });
            });
```

If there is a way in which this code can be properly written, I would appreciate the guidance! Like I have earlier said somewhere, am new to programming. I further need to refresh a certain element where am echoing the id value from my database after the ajax has run successfully so that the number of downloads is updated on link click.